# Issue with overlapping ScrollViews

Tags: android, scrollview

I must make a layout with 2 overlapping ScrollViews. One is an article with a "see comments" button. The other view is transparent and contains the comments, and is shown on top of the article when the "see comments" button is clicked. The problem is that when the comments are shown and do not fill the screen, touching the screen out of the screen (eg. below the button "Retour" on the image shown below. This is an iphone screenshot, the design on android is different) scrolls the article.

[image]

Also, the "Voir les Commentaires" button can be clicked, even with another layout on top of it.

Why is the view below not disabled (button, scroll...) when there's another one on top of it? How can it be done?

Anybody can help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:background="#e7e7e8">

        <!-- header -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/article_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- article -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#50000000" android:visibility="gone">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/comment_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <!-- comments -->

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, I deleted my comment ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use a new Activity for your comment and use Transucent theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Some alternatives Themes should fit your needs (Dialog for instance)

or a blurried background: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As for the button "Voir les Commentaires", you could set it to enabled = false when the second layer is visible. And I'm not quite sure atm, but I think you can do the same for the bottom ScrollView.